# How to sort dictionary where value is a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

this is my dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_4': [41,43]
}
```

and I want to sort it by values so that times with the biggest difference of the two elements in the list are placed first.

This is what I want:

```
mydict = {
    'item_3': [54,191],
    'item_1': [7,19],
    'item_2': [0,3],
    'item_4': [41,43],
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Edit:

I got a response with this

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: abs(item[1][0]-item[1][1]),reverse=True)}
```

And I also read some documentation on it, but don't understand the logic, what exactly is happening here?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered data structures, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You cannot sort dictionaries. See `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort a dictionary, but you can sort **keys** by a certain property of **values**:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(mydict.keys(), 
                     key=lambda x: abs(mydict[x][0]-mydict[x][1]), 
                     reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: abs(item[1][0]-item[1][1]),reverse=True)}
```

Comment: Note that you need 3.7 or later version of python interpreter to use this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned a dictionary is not ordered, however you can get a sorted list of two-item tuples representing the key-value pairs of your dictionary:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: abs(item[1][0] - item[1][1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

since [python3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) dictionaries are insertion ordered (dictionaries remember the order of items inserted), so if you have a python version >=3.6 you can use:

```
dict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: abs(t[1][0] - t[1][1]), reverse=True))
```

output:

```
{'item_3': [54, 191], 'item_1': [7, 19], 'item_2': [0, 3], 'item_4': [41, 43]}
```

for other versions of python <3.6 you can use [OrderDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict)